# Error when adding network interface to VM on KVM host using virsh

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virsh, virt-manager, virt-install

I'm attempting to script adding a network interface to a centos 6 guest. I know the interface can be set up using the **virt-manager** gui but it's highly desirable for it to be added as part of an Ansible playbook using **virsh attach-interface** or alternatively as part of **virt-install**.

The desired interface should look like this (although with a new mac adress)

```
<interface type='direct'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:39:f8:3a'/>
  <source dev='enp3s0' mode='bridge'/>
  <target dev='macvtap8'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <alias name='net0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

I have been unable to replicate this using **virsh attach-interface** or **virt-install**. I've tried using the following

```
virsh attach-interface 16 --type direct --source enp3s0 --model virtio --config --live
```

but this, unfortunately, doesn't set the source mode so I end up with the following interface

```
<interface type='direct'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:e1:d8:2c'/>
  <source dev='enp3s0' mode='vepa'/>
  <target dev='macvtap15'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <alias name='net1'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

in an ideal world I would like to be able to do something like

```
virsh attach-interface 16 --type direct --source enp3s0 --model virtio --mode bridge --config --live
```

but this returns the following error and I can't find the correct option to specify for this operation.

```
error: command 'attach-interface' doesn't support option --mode
```

Comment: I never use macvtap, but actual Linux bridge. This makes VM setup a bit easier and more reliable, and you don't necessarily have to create a libvirt virtual network either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already know the exact XML you want for the NIC, you should just avoid the `virsh attach-interface` command and instead use `virsh attach-device`. The `attach-device` command accepts the full XML document directly for the new device. `attach-interface` is just a dumb wrapper around `attach-device` which generates XML for you. So since you have the XML already there's no point in using `attach-interface`